# MongoDb restoring broken Database

Tags: mongodb, windows-server-2012-r2

Running MongoDB Server on Windows.
I had a big Db, with backup etc. but retarded as I am, instead of using the Shell to delete some entries, I first copied them to another directory, and then deleted them via explorer. Of course, nothing did work, because MongoDb did miss some entries and did not even start to work properly, with an I/O Error in the Log(File not found). So, I copied the files back where they belonged, again via explorer, retried it, and now I still get the ErrorMsg in the Log, that some file is missing. The weird thing is, that file never existed in those folders, I deleted...
Well so now, at least I still have a backup dump made with mongodump, but I can not restore the dump, because to restore, I have to start the MongoDbServer which will not start, because some folders of my DB entries are missing(the service will start, I can't access the server instance though), and to include the missing folders I have to use mongorestore... Some bad loop, I got going there...
So I created a new DB and wanted to restore my old dump in the new DB, but now I get a invalid header error when using mongorestore --gzip --archive -d test "dump_path"

Any help, how to resolve my problem?

Answer (score 3):

Solved it... I created a new DB, started the mongodbserver but this time, instead of writing mongorestore --gzip --archive filename dumppath, which exited with an too many arguments error, you have to type:
mongorestore --gzip --archive="filename" dumppath, and then everything works as one would expect...